Fix strange problem in firebase cloud messagging try to get server key
In my Flutter app among other functions there is the one for users to write posts, and I would like every time a post is published all the other people receive a notification that a post has been published by a user (and username appears) , like "user_00293 just posted".  To turn on notifications in my Flutter app I need a server key, and it's currently turned off.  I saw on the internet that to activate it I have to go to the API section and press the "enable" button.  In reality, all the Firebase APIs are already activated for me, and in fact the "manage" button appears.  However, the server key still does not appear and if I try to go to the recommended Google Cloud page I get the following error message: Failed to load.
SEND FEEDBACKRETRY
There was an error while loading /apis/library/googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com?authuser=0&project=nect-9a926&hl=en&pli=1.  Please try again.
It may be a browser or network issue.  Go to the loading issues help page  to troubleshoot the issue.
Request ID: 13699682557882146690
On the internet I am advised to do a series of actions which I have already done, but which did not solve the problem: I used 5 different browsers, and in each I deleted the Cache, then I also tried to create different projects from Google accounts different on different devices, but I always get the same error.  How do I fix this, and view the server key so I can put push notifications in my app?  Thanks in advance and I await your kind feedback.

From the Firebase FAQ:

Can new projects enable the legacy Cloud Messaging API?
No. Starting from 5/20/2024, new projects will no longer be allowed to enable our legacy APIs.

It is no longer possible to mint server keys for Firebase Cloud Messages. These keys are only usable with the legacy API, which was deprecated in June 2023, and will be retired in June 2024.
To use Firebase Cloud Messaging going forward, you'll have to use the v1 versioned API (that was introduced in 2017). For more on this see the full documentation on migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 and my answer to Does anyone know what to do in case of legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) APIs will be discontinued?.
