Enable Cloud messaging to get The server Key
i have a problem in Firebase cloud messaging i can't Enable the cloud massaging to get the Server Key the page of cloud messaging not loading(Failed to load.) the problem is that enter image description here
i'am trying to Update the dart SDK and flutter Version but i don't have any result so what is the solution to load the page of cloud messaging to can Enable This service of Firebase

The FCM server key is no longer available, as the API that you need it for will be sunset in June. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536371/fix-strange-problem-in-firebase-cloud-messagging-try-to-get-server-key/78536576#78536576
